# Update property inside a multi-level array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb

I'm trying to develop an API that returns a JSON containing the number of people interested in playing a game at a certain hour in a certain server. Very specific decision.

So the user should be able to say:

> I'll be playing Amazing Game today at 4pm on x-server

So I have an `Agenda` object with contains a date and an array of games. The `Game` object contains a title and a list of slots. Each `Slot` contains an hour (so each game has 24 slots) and an array of servers. And finally, each `Server` has a name and a total of interested players.

I'm using mongoDB for that.

Here's the JSON so far. It's big so I'll share only a small part of it:

```
{
  "_id":{"$oid":"608ed34799fc933a1263664a"},
  "date":"2021-05-04",
  "games":[
    {
      "_id":{"$oid":"608ea801b8ba823613c49e2f"},
      "title":"Amazing Game",
      "active":true,
      "slots":[
        {
          "hour":0,
          "servers":[
            {
              "_id":{"$oid":"608eb2e1b8ba823613c49e31"},
              "name":"x-server",
              "active":true,
              "total":0
            },
            {
              "_id":{"$oid":"608eb32fb8ba823613c49e32"},
              "name":"russian-server",
              "active":true,
              "total":0
            },
            {
              "_id":{"$oid":"608eb33ab8ba823613c49e33"},
              "name":"usa-server",
              "active":true,
              "total":0
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "hour":1,
          "servers":[
            {
              "_id":{"$oid":"608eb2e1b8ba823613c49e31"},
              "name":"x-server",
              "active":true,
              "total":0
            },
            {
              "_id":{"$oid":"608eb32fb8ba823613c49e32"},
              "name":"russian-server",
              "active":true,
              "total":0
            },
            {
              "_id":{"$oid":"608eb33ab8ba823613c49e33"},
              "name":"usa-server",
              "active":true,
              "total":0
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I have two questions:

1. Am I modeling this right? This json seems confusing and I wonder if I could come up with something simpler. Perhaps I'm missing something.
2. I am having some trouble updating the total of players in a certain server for a slot in a game. I was trying to do this using the `updateOne` directly from mongoose but after much attempts I'm wondering if maybe I should get the entire agenda from the database first, manipulate the object in javascript so I can update the value of the property and then use the `save()` method to save the entire document again.

Let's say I want to increment the total by one in Amazing Game at 1 o'clock for x-server.

I've tried:

`db.agendas.updateOne({_id:ObjectId('608ed070b27d3a37be167bcf'), "games.title": "Amazing Game", "games.slots.hour": 1, "games.slots.servers.name": "x-server"}, {$set: { "games.$.slots.$.servers.$.total": 10}})`

And got:

`MongoError: Too many positional (i.e. '$') elements found in path 'games.$.slots.$.servers.$.total'`

Comment: You might try the online [*JSON schema tool*](https://www.jsonschema.net/login), it can generate a schema from JSON and you can play with the structure. There are also JSON validators (e.g. [*jsonlint.com*](https://jsonlint.com/)), even editors (e.g. [this one](https://www.jeremydorn.com/json-editor)) that build a form from a schema that is helpful for validating the structure and creating sample JSON files. Go play. :-)

Comment: The `$` array update operator cannot be used with more than _one_ level of nesting of arrays - hence the error.